# why Java not release memory

Tags: java, multithreading, memory

I'm a junior in Java, facing a memory leaking problem. I always thought java won't have a memory problem but I got one. Below is my testing code.

I create a large ArrayList in getList() method, and keep calling this method in the main thread. I thought the list:

```
ArrayList<String> list = t.getList();
```

in loop is a local var, and should be released in the next round because a new object would be created. But jvm didn't do that. This thread keep eating all the memory. Would anyone tell me the reason? Thanks!

Testing code:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {


public static void main(String[] args){

    test t = new test();
    for(int k = 0; k < 10000; k ++){
        ArrayList<String> list = t.getList();

        System.out.println(k);
    }

}

public ArrayList<String> getList(){
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i ++){
        String a = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
            a += "aaaa";
        }
        list.add(a);
    }

    return list;
}
}
```

Modified Problem:
in the modified problem, the thread also keep eating memory. But I thought it should release the memory during each round, but it didn't. So it occupied more and more memory.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    test t = new test();
    for(int k = 0; k < 10000; k ++){
        String str1 = "string1";
        String str2 = "string2";
        double value = t.calculate(str1, str2);

        System.out.println(k + " " + value);
    }

}

public double calculate(String str1, String str2){
    double value = 0.0;

    ArrayList<String> list1 = getList(str1);
    ArrayList<String> list2 = getList(str2);

    value = cal(list1, list2); //will get the value based on lists

    return value;

}


public ArrayList<String> getList(String str1){
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //will generate  a long list

    return list;
}
```

Comment: You don't technically have a memory leak. What does "eating all the memory" mean specifically? How much memory? How do you know that this thread is responsible? You are, after all, creating tens of millions of objects in each call to `getList()`.

Comment: It's not OOMEing for me. You must not have a big enough memory max to hold one iteration.

Comment: well its not necessary GC release the memory in the very next round.But yes its true it should be released on the GC run

Comment: @chrylis I am simply monitoring "Windows Task Manager"--"Processes" to check the memory occupied. While the printed "i" going, the memory occupied by javaw.exe keeps increasing. I got nearly 1,800+MB when i reaches 80. I think it's abnormal.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  I got nearly 1,800+MB memory used when i reaches 80. I think it's abnormal.

Comment: No, it's really not abnormal. You're creating an incredible number of objects on each pass, and the JVM is keeping a memory pool that seems reasonably balanced between overall allocation and generation size.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that it's because of the iterated string concatenation:

```
a += "aaaa";
```

Not because the `List` isn't being released.

At the end of it all, `a` has 40,000,000 characters in it.

Comment: That's OK. You had me checking my math. Ha ha. :-D

Comment: The `list` probably has 40,000,000 characters in it. Every call to `getList()` generates a list of 100,000 elements and each element contains 400 characters.

Comment: @WillieWheeler I got nearly 1,800+MB memory used when 'i' reaches 80. And during this period, the occupied memory keeps increasing. But, should it release the memory and only occupied a much smaller space even when 'i' increasing.

Answer (score 3):

One call to `getList` will allocate space for 2000000000 characters (this includes the intermediate results for the string concatenations). Thats 4GB, not counting overhead. All this is done in a loop 10000 times giving total allocations of 40TB.

GC is doing a good job if this program executes for a while.

Comment: +1 for `GC is doing a good job if this program executes for a while.`

Comment: +1 for including the intermediate results for the string concats.

Comment: @Henry thanks for the answer. Above is a simplified example of the problem I am encountering. Maybe it's my fault to not clarify that.

Comment: @Henry I modified the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Common misconception is that the GC releases memory as soon at it not needed.  The cost of running the GC is high, and so it is delayed as long as possible (Unless you use Azul's Zing in which case it is always concurrent)

This means it is completely normal to see memory consumption increase as you create more and more garbage and the ONLY way to know if you have a memory leak is to look at consumption AFTER a Full GC.  Until a Full GC is run you can be sure that some objects which might have been cleaned up have not been.

> But I thought it should release the memory during each round, but it didn't.

There is no way for the GC to know this is a good time to run.  If you want to confirm this would be a good time, you can do a

```
System.gc();
```

between runs.  The memory usage after call this should be pretty stable.  The reason this call is not used more often is that usually it makes things worse, unless you know for example, that at that point you have dumped almost all the memory the application has used.

> facing a memory leaking problem. I always thought java won't have a memory problem but I got one.

You can have a memory leak in a Java program, but I don't see any evidence you have one.

If you want to see a memory leak save all the ArrayList in an ArrayList in main.  This should lead to an OutOfMemoryError and you have a leak.